# What are some ways to escape a string for use with basic regular expressions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby uses extended regular expressions. This example fails when used with basic regular expressions:

```
pattern = Regexp.escape('a string with (parentheses)')
=> "a\\ string\\ with\\ \\(parentheses\\)"
```

The issue here seems to be `\(` and `\)` character combinations. I'm trying to use `pattern` as an argument to csplit (which uses BRE) from a Ruby script:

```
`csplit sample_file '%#{pattern}%'`
```

Comment: It is expected behavior that `()` gets escaped since it is a capturing group. So what's the problem ?

Comment: @HamZa `()` must be escaped in some regex engines when they are used as capture group delimiters e.g. POSIX (unlike PCRE) However I'm not sure if this is true for Ruby

Comment: @hek2mgl Are you telling me that you need to escape the parentheses in Ruby to actually make a capturing group ?

Comment: @HamZa I'm just telling that this is not uncommon to escape the beginning and end of a capture group. (because POSIX requires this, check `sed`) . I'm a Ruby noob ;)

Comment: @HamZa they get interpreted as subexpression markers.

Comment: @hek2mgl [.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) in ruby is something like [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote) in PHP. Also, check [this](http://rubular.com/r/hgcwn5qYCZ).

Comment: @HamZa Thanks for the links and pointing this out  ;) Rubular is now in my favorites

Answer (score 0):

So the goal here is to only escape characters that will have special meaning when interpreted by a basic regular expression engine.  From looking at a table on [this page](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Regular.html), my understanding is that the only characters this includes are the following:

```
. ^ $ [ ] * \
```

So we just need to add a backslash immediately before each of these characters in a string, which you can do with something like the following:

```
pattern = 'a string with (parentheses)'.gsub(/(?=[.^$\[\]*\\])/, '\\')
```

In this case it will just return the string unmodified because parentheses aren't in the set of characters to be replaced, but this would turn something like `'foo[bar].gif'` into `'foo\\[bar\\]\\.gif'`.